# Import Openpyxl on Python 2 or Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have the following codes running fine in Python 3. But I got an error of "no module named openpyxl" when i run in Python 2.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
```

I did try "pip install openpyxl", and "!pip install openpyxl" in Python 2 in Bluemix but still not working. Any advice? Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Did you confirm that `pip` actually installed the module in the expected location? You might be installing the module for a different version of Python or in a virtual environment that you aren't using.

Comment: Hi! thx for the reply! sorry i am new to python, and plz correct me if i understand yours in a wrong way: are u saying that the code i used "pip instll openpyxl" is atcually installing openpyxl module in Python 2?  Bluemix has python 2 so i guess i need to find the pip that's working for python 2? thx for your help!

Comment: in what ever version of python you are using you can do `import pip ; pip.main(["install","openpyxl"])` to install it with the _exact_ same version as that interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

On my Linux Mint (Rafaela) installation, with python 2.7 & python 3.5, I have to use "pip3 install" to load into python 3.